# Infinite Scroll does not scroll

Tags: python, selenium

My code scrapes titles of youtube videos, but doesnt scroll down to scrape all titles.

When selenium opens the browser, it doesnt even scroll at all. How can i modify the code to scroll down infinitely and eventually scrape all titles.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url='https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=doctor'
driver.get(url)
content=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    titles = soup.findAll('a', id='video-title')
    for title in titles:
        print(title.text)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `scrollHeight` to get current height, but that value doesn't change when you scroll. Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight) to see that you should use `scrollTop` instead. It also says that you should use this equation to detect if the scroll is at bottom:

```
element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url='https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=doctor'
driver.get(url)
content=driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    print('In While True')
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", last_height)
    print('executed')
    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    print('slept')
    titles = soup.findAll('a', id='video-title')
    for title in titles:
        print(title.text)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
```